# On Foundation 5, what CSS is generated by setting $include-html-classes to false?

Tags: zurb-foundation

Specifying `$include-html-classes` to `false` and then importing Foundation 5 to your Sass file still [generates a bunch of CSS](http://pastebin.com/3J2U1szq).  Looks like some of it is meta stuff for versioning  information I suppose, but some of it looks like HTML classes.  I thought the whole point of using this variable was to remove HTML classes?

Here's my SCSS file:

```
@import "../foundation/settings";
$include-html-classes: false;
@import "foundation";
```

This wasn't a problem in Foundation 4.  What are these styles and how can I get rid of 'em?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like it is a bug where new presentational classes have been added above the conditionals. Since you question is how to fix it, here is the process if you don't want to wait until it is fixed officially.

Move your Scss into a different directory or fork the foundation bower repo.

Update your config.rb (line 2) to point to the new files, this is relative to your project directory

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
add_import_path "some_other_directory/foundation/scss"
```

Then you will need to modify each file that generates presentational classes. Luckily Compass/Sass gives us the exact place to look.

```
/* line 259, ../bower_components/foundation/scss/foundation/components/_global.scss */
meta.foundation-version {
  font-family: "/5.1.0/";
}
```

On line 296 you will see the conditional line:

```
@if $include-html-global-classes {
```

and all of the classes that have been added above it.

You will need to move this line to 260 and it should look like the following.

```
@include exports("global") {

  @if $include-html-global-classes {

    meta.foundation-version {
      font-family: "/5.1.0/";
    }
```

Since this is Scss you could either leave or correct the indentation to match.

You would need to repeat this for each file that generates CSS with Compass. If you are running compass watch, you can just check or reload your stylesheets/app.css after each correction.

Comment: that worked, and it was actually a pretty easy fix, thanks.  I added a [bug report on github](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/4555) and will send include the new partials.